# How to hide a search field on top of a UIScrollview

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiscrollview, uikit

I am trying to hide the search field by default in my app like seen in multiple Apple apps.

[image] [image]

*(Image credit: OS X Daily [http://osxdaily.com/2017/07/27/search-notes-ios/)](http://osxdaily.com/2017/07/27/search-notes-ios/)_)*

Right now, the search field is on top of the contained view and it works fine. I could set a default offset to hide the search bar, but it won't prevent being shown when the scroll content size length is smaller than the scrollview.

By the way, I am NOT using a UITableView inside the UIScrollView, it's a custom view with subviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hook the height constraint of you custom search view as IBOutlet and make this to hide it

```
self.searHeightcon.constant = 0
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Show

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   if(scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0)
    {
       self.searHeightcon.constant = 50
    }
    else
    {
        self.searHeightcon.constant = 0
    }

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

Comment: Interesting. But I am not sure how to show it back when I am scrolling up.

Comment: see inside **scrollViewDidScroll** accroding to y offset manage hide/show of the sceach

Answer (score 0):

If you always set the `contentHeight` to be same or larger than the scroll view’s height you can hide it by starting at an offset.